# Get comment nodes in DOM deep level

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

How can I get an array or array-like (JQuery object) containing all the comment elements in the DOM?
[JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) `contents()` only retrieve 1 level elements.

The broader problem: I need to remove all the elements between 2 text comments in my DOM. Comments can also be in child elements.

```
...html code...
<!--remove from here-->
...code...
<!--finish removing-->
...html code...
```

So after the method, HTML DOM should look like:

```
...html code...
...html code...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) with `whatToShow` set to `NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL` to see all nodes on your document.

```js
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,
  null,
  false
);

var commentList = [];

while (treeWalker.nextNode()){
  // keep only comments
  if (treeWalker.currentNode.nodeType === 8) 
    commentList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
}

var node;
while (node !== commentList[1]) {
  node = commentList[0].nextSibling;
  node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
}
```

```html
<!--Folowing element will be deleted-->
<span> Hello world</span>
<!-- the next one should be kept -->
<span> keep me !</span>
```

Comment: the deletion part will only work with the given structure : delete everything between two comments if there is only two of them. You may need to check whether those are the good ones or not.

Comment: I admit that I haven't heard of that yet :)
I see that it's pretty well cross browser supported so it's good.
Is it more efficient than removing text from the innerHtml with RegEx?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's way more efficient yes ! see [this piece of history](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3702797). Also, TreeWalker is really powerful, definitely give it a try.

Comment: BTW - even better for my case is to use the filter: "SHOW_COMMENT" and remove the nextSibling of the target comment until the next target comment || null.